# why is 4 printed as prime number

Tags: java

I have an array and I want to know what are the prime numbers in this array. 
I know that number 4 is not a "Prime number" but it still prints me the number 4
what am I missing? 
I know I can't add on the second  if:" if (isPrime && number != 4 )but I just want to understand what is wrong with my code and why number 4 is printed 
Thanks

```
    int numbe []= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    System.out.println("Prime Numbers are:");
    for(int number : numbe)
    {
        boolean isPrime =true;
        for (int i = 2; i < number / 2 ; i++)
        {
            if ((number % i) == 0)
            {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime)
            System.out.println("Prime Number: " + number);
    }
```

Comment: for loop should be `for (int i = 2; i <= number / 2 ; i++)`.

Comment: @anoopknr this should be an answer ( ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The for loop's body is never executed with number 4.

Your condition for executing a loop is `i < number / 2` and i is defined with `int i = 2`.

That means the condition will resolve to `2 < 4 / 2` that is to say `2 < 2`, and 2 is not strictly inferior to itself. Your comparison operator should be "inferior **or equals**", which is `<=`

As such it will at least try to check if 4 can be divided by 2, which it can, thus marking 4 as non-prime.

<strike>Maybe you could have started with i=1 instead.</strike> Er, actually not.

Answer (score 5):

You have made mistake in your *for-loop* `for (int i = 2; i < number / 2 ; i++)`.

Your `for-loop` should be :-

```
    for (int i = 2; i <= number / 2 ; i++){

      // Your for-loop content.

    }
```

In your program, when `n=4` then `i < number / 2 ;` statement fails because `i` is initialized  to `2` *(i=2)* and `i < number / 2 ;` *ie, (2<2)* . So the `for-loop` does not get executed. So by modifying to  `i <= number / 2 ;` the `for loop` executes for one time and `if ((number % i) == 0)` get executed and `isPrime = false;` works.

Comment: Why? Can you explain why this solves the issue? Elaborate a bit on the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5):

You have to change the inner for loop as follow

```
    for (int i = 2; i <= number / 2 ; i++) {
        ...
    }
```

Otherwise for `4` you will never enter the loop (`4/2` is `2` and `2 < 2` is `false` for the first iteration) and the variable `isPrime` remains `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Perhaps also worth pointing out that you can use `i * i <= number` as the guard.

Answer (score 3):

Your logic in the for loop is not correct. Correct Program is:

Correction: because loop terminates if i is less then 4/2 = 2, So it never goes inside the loop

```
int numbe []= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    System.out.println("Prime Numbers are:");
    for(int number : numbe)
    {
        boolean isPrime =true;
        for (int i = 2; i <= number / 2 ; i++)
        {
            if ((number % i) == 0)
            {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime)
            System.out.println("Prime Number: " + number);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's better :)

Answer (score 1):

Because of  `for (int i = 2; i < number / 2 ; i++)` condition.

here for number =4, it checks 2<2, which is false, hence it doesn't go inside for loop  and prints 4 is prime number.

You need to change your condition to below:-

```
for (int i = 2; i <= number / 2 ; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your for loop starts at 2 and terminates if i is less then 4/2 = 2, actually, you never enter in the for loop.

Change the exit condition with i <= number / 2